# Will the Google Cast extension work on the Beta Channel on my Chromebook?

Tags: google-chrome-os, google-cast, chromebook

The Google Cast extension would not work on my Chromebook Pixel which I had pinned to the beta channel of ChromeOS.  Once I did a recovery and reverted to the stable channel on my Chromebook, the Google Cast extension works.

I 100% get that beta channel will (almost certainly) not be officially supported, but I'm hoping as part of being forward-looking the extension will eventually/soon get to "seems to work" status on the beta channel -- because today's beta channel leads to tomorrow's stable channel.

Comment: Do you have any more details about "would not work" on your Pixel? Did the extension fail to install, fail to load, fail to inject the content script...?